# IBM Integration Bus choose which Queue read first

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I have 5 input Queues, 5 message flows for each. After some processing messages from all queues go to one transport queue.

Is there a possibility to set a priority across queues, for example messages from input queue 1 will always be processed and put in the transport queue first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the [message priority](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q022910_.htm).

> You set the priority of a message (in the Priority field of the MQMD
>   structure) when you put the message on a queue
>   ... you can create messages having priorities between 0 (the lowest) and 9
>   (the highest).

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the Sequence Node to done this task.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc28010_.htm